# CSS: truncating a row of images to the same height

Tags: html, css, image

I have a bunch of image thumbnails I'm displaying in a web page.  All of the images are 256 pixels wide, and I'm shrinking them 50% with `<img width="128px" ...>`

Most images have a 4x3 ratio, so they grid quite nicely over several rows.

However, some images are very tall (e.g. 256x1200).  I would like to specify a maximum height for these images, but the image must be truncated (i.e. showing only the top part of the image) and not scaled (which would undesirably squish the image).

I've tried specifying CSS `img { max-height="128" }` but of course that is giving me the undesired scaling.

So:  how can I specify a maximum height that will cause the image to truncate and not scale?

**update:** thanks all, I've added an example below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wrap them in a classed div, set the height on the div to 128, and then set `overflow: hidden` for that class.

Comment: And if you want to center the image vertically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141865/responsive-vertical-center-with-overflow-hidden

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the image in a div, set the div's height and width to what you want. Add a style of overflow:hidden to the div.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who responded... here's an example of the solution.

```
<div style="max-height: 170px; overflow: hidden;">
    <img width="128" align="top" src="img1.jpg">
    <img width="128" align="top" src="img2.jpg">
    <img width="128" align="top" src="img3.jpg">
</div>
```

Each of the images taller than 170 pixels is truncated and the images align to the top.  I put the style information inline for brevity's sake.  In my real code it's in a style section.

Comment: Note: align attribute on <img> is not supported in HTML5 and is deprecated in HTML 4.01

Comment: @EvereQ, what is the recommended replacement?

Comment: it has been deprecated in favor of style sheets (CSS) - use 'vertical-align' in CSS instead :)

Answer (score 0):

If we're showing a row of images whose width is fluid (e.g. four columns of images each with width 25%), and we want their height to scale as their width changes, one way would be to use a row of divs with background-image: url(...) instead of `<img>` tags.

This allows us to set padding-bottom on the divs which will give them a height that is a percentage of their container's width. For example, if we wanted perfect square images, we should set their width % and padding-bottom % to be the same. You can adjust to keep whatever aspect ratio you want for the images.

```
.image-container {
width: 33.33333333%;
padding-bottom: 33.33333333%;
margin: 0;
float: left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/qxn87wmo/20/

It's then just a matter of setting background-size, background-position as desired.