# Responsive vertical center with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overflow, vertical-alignment

After searching both Stack Overflow and Google I still wonder how to vertical center a image that is bigger than it's parent element. I use no height, just max-height, because I want to make a responsive solution, without jQuery. If possible.

Here is some code:

```
<div style="max-height: 425px; overflow: hidden;">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/jofNR_WkoCE/maxresdefault.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

to center vertically a bigger image you can use the construction and css bellow

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/jofNR_WkoCE/maxresdefault.jpg">
</div>
```

And css:

```
.img-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:425px;
}

.img-wrapper img{
    position: absolute;
    top:-100%; left:0; right: 0; bottom:-100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PRJHw/5/)

Comment: Works excellent in webkit browsers! Can you make it work in Firefox as well?

Comment: @ExtPro Actually this solution works fine without using any Javascript, but only in webkit browsers

Comment: Found a little trick for Firefox. Change top and bottom to -100%. http://jsfiddle.net/PRJHw/5/

Comment: Nice! But as i said i would like to not use a fixed width, that's bad for responsive purpose

Comment: Not sure why everyone has upvoted this since the question clearly stipulates `max-height` only, no static `height`.

Comment: Here's a blog post that did it for me (container has a fixed `height`, img has `top` and `transform`): http://jonrohan.codes/fieldnotes/vertically-center-clipped-image/

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to make it work with only a `max-height` (as opposed to a fixed height) set on the container.

The bad news is that it requires an additional wrapper element.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/jofNR_WkoCE/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 425px;
}

.img-container {
    max-height: inherit;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}

.img-wrapper img {
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: This is great for situations where absolute positioning causes issues. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nowdays you can achieve this by using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox):

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/jofNR_WkoCE/maxresdefault.jpg">
</div>
```

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 425px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

View example on CodePen:

- https://codepen.io/runonce86/pen/vYrpYvG

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need to use `img` tags ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Az2mY/)):

CSS

```
.imageContainer {
    margin: 0; 
    height: 200px; /* change it to your value*/
    width: 200px; /* or use fixed width*/
    background: transparent url('') no-repeat center;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="imageContainer" style="background-image: url('http://deepwish.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/butterfly2_large.jpg');"></div>
```

Comment: I would like to use it like a image (<img>) and not a background

Comment: @Henrik Albrechtsson Afraid you're going to need to use some JS for this :( Because the container and/or image(?) can have variable sizes, in order for the offsets to be calculated in CSS at least one will have to be hard coded unless its calculated at runtime (JS), unless the image is scaled

Comment: Actually [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/PRJHw/2) works fine without using any Javascript, but only in webkit browsers

Comment: @Henrik Albrechtsson Not sure I'd call a specific browser subset workaround a solution :S But yes, it can be done in webkit- what support are you after?

Comment: Would be glad if I could support the most common browsers Firefox, Chrome and Safari

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body >

    <div style="max-height: 425px;border:1px solid;max-width:500px;overflow:hidden">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/jofNR_WkoCE/maxresdefault.jpg" style='position: relative;top: -231px;left: -500px;'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using pixels to position the image makes it non responsive

Answer (score -2):

if you want to make a responsive image, try using
 `<div style="">`
                 `<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/jofNR_WkoCE/maxresdefault.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">`
`</div>`

Comment: I want to use overflow hidden to remove the black edges from the [image](http://img.youtube.com/vi/jofNR_WkoCE/maxresdefault.jpg) above